# how to pass unique data for each Angular ui-view (several views) which produced with laravel Blades foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel-blade

I have a **blade** page with a **foreach** loop.
Inside each loop: there is an Angular **ui-view** , and an Angular **init** function (**myFunc**). each loop prepares a different variable (**$foo**) for **myFunc**.
How can i send each **$foo** to its specific ui-view (template)?

I'm trying to prepare some information (list of people's name) from Laravel Backend to Angular ui-view. while I'm using Blade in the middle for creating several ui-views for each name. And each produced ui-view must have a unique $foo (name) variable to work with. I know it does not make sense! But this is the way I wanna do it.. thanks

**Blade** file:

```
@foreach($foos as $foo)

   <div  ng-init="myFunc( {{ $foo }} )"> </div>
   <div ui-view='myViewState' ></div>

@endforeach
```

my **Angular** template (**myViewState**) :

```
<div> {{initResult}} </div>
```

my js file:(which is **Wrong**) - All produced ui-views display the **same thing** ( latest $scope.initResult changes)

```
$scope.myFunc=function(foo){

 $scope.initResult=foo;

}
```